# remove nvidia graphics card and use integrated intel graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a desktop ubuntu 14.04 system that has an nvidia graphics card and intel graphics on the motherboard. I Want to remove the nvidia card from the system and use only the intel graphics.  The system is currently running the nvidia 3.41 driver.  I'm new to linux and need help with the steps I have to take to switch over to the intel integrated graphics. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html this allows you to select which driver you are using

Comment: also https://github.com/beidl/prime-indicator

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to install any extra packages, switching between the nVidia GPU (Performance Mode) and the Intel GPU (Power Saving Mode) could be achieved by using the **NVIDIA X Server Settings**, which has already been installed along with your driver.

First thing you will need to do is to find the **NVIDIA X Server Settings** application from your dash:
[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

And go to the **PRIME Profiles** page
[image: PRIME Profiles]

From there, after entering your password you will be able to switch between your GPUs:
[image: Enter password]

The last step is to log out, and it's done!
[image: logout prompt]

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: don't thank the answerer, but click the grey **☑** under small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)