# Ubuntu temporarily freezes and then highlights text when unfreezing

Tags: freeze

Irregularly, when I am using a program that displays text (gedit, neovim, firefox, etc.) the operating system will freeze for a few seconds.  When the operating system unfreezes, the operating system selects about a paragraph of text either above or below the current cursor location. The text selection happens even if I am not trying to select text when the operating system freezes.

It currently happens the most when I am just scrolling up and down through a long file (nothing else pressed).

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 in the VirtualBox 5.1.22.  The system comes with two graphics cards: the default intel driver and an NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M.

Any help on how to debug this problem would be appreciated. I don't know where to start.  I'm happy to provide any information that may help.

Comment: Could it be that this happens when you have a mouse button pressed? If the system freezes and when it resumes processes mouse and keyboard events, including a scroll, you would get this effect. You might want to focus on the reasons for the intermittent freezes (CPU load? paging?) and ignore the text highlighting symptoms.

Comment: Thanks!  It happens most often when I am scrolling up and down using my laptop track pad.  I'm currently looking into and will update with what I find. It just froze with less than 10% CPU load (monitoring using htop).  I'll look into paging next.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recent problem with intel and Nvidia graphics card. My system crashed tty7 many times.

when your system come to low energy, use intel, and when use maximum 
Performance take Nvidia.

Try to see a YouTube video and unplug power freeze?

try to keep at maximum performance on energy options freeze?

The only solution I have is decide what you want to use and uninstall the other driver. (Nvidia or intel)
That works for me.

Comment: Please se this https://askubuntu.com/questions/594787/remove-nvidia-graphics-card-and-use-integrated-intel-graphics?rq=1